# ASP.Net Not Authorized user URL and URLRewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, webforms

Lets say I have a website `www.example.com` and this website only for authorized users so I have a log in page called `Login.aspx`, when the user request a page called

```
www.example.com/books/55
```

to an authorized user it's working fine, but when the not authorized user requests this page the user will be shown like

```
www.example.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fbooks%2f55
```

I want to make this url more friendly to keep shown the url like the user enters it

```
www.example.com/books/55
```

and show the log in page (facebook behaviour) or make this url more friendly in another way.

Comment: This is standard behaviour, i don't beleive you can change it and you shouldn't want to. The return URL is being correctly url encoded http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @BenRobinson I know it's a normal behavior but are there any way using URLRewite to change it or make it just more friendly, I like the facebook behavior just requist any facebook page withwut login and you will see it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, url rewriting can be done.
In Global file under Application_Start,

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("AdminLoginRoute", "Admin/Login", "~/Admin/AdminLogin.aspx");
```

For example you have a page named Admin/AdminLogin.aspx

The above code will replace the name with Admin/Login

Books/55 in your code appears to be dynamic.
You can get dynamic url by passing dynamic arguments like:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("AdminLoginRoute", "Admin/Login/{Id}", "~/Admin/AdminLogin.aspx");
```

Here Id is dynamic.

Comment: As I understand it the OP is not asking how to change the page route, the OP wants the querystring parameter to not be URL encoded.

Comment: What I want is that , I want to keep the url for not authorized user as its requested, or make it more friendly without any encoding
I tried to use your code @Manu but it's not work for me